# How do I manage and present a surface in SDL2's rust bindings?

Tags: rust, sdl-2

I'm trying to write a program that works as a whiteboard. However, as I keep drawing, the program has to keep track of more and more points, which slows down the program and causes it to lag.

I want to try and keep the previous state of the frame, and only draw any new points I add.

Here's a skeleton of my program:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq)]
struct Center {
    point: Point,
    radius: i32,
}

fn main() {
//...
    let mut canvas = window.into_canvas().build().unwrap();
    let mut points: Vec<Center> = Vec::new();

    'running: loop {
        for event in event_pump.poll_iter() {
            match event {
// other events here, like quit
                Event::MouseMotion {
                    x, y, mousestate, ..
                } => 'draw: {
                    // here, I add new points if the mouse is held
        }
        canvas.set_draw_color(Color::RGB(255, 255, 255)); // make the background white
        canvas.clear();

        canvas.set_draw_color(Color::RGB(0, 0, 0));
        draw_centers(&mut canvas, &points);
        canvas.present();

}
```

I've tried not calling `canvas.clear()` every frame, but that just makes the entire window black.

Comment: Try calling `canvas.set_draw_color(Color::RGB(255, 255, 255))` and `canvas.clear()` before the loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried that and it does not work.

Comment: You can just not clear the canvas, I think.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman unfortunately that does not work either.